# JSONP Failure for Yelp Fusion API

Tags: jquery, api, reactjs, jsonp, yelp

I am a growing React developer, using Mac OSX with a Chrome browser. I have worked through many different methods attempting to receive JSONP from the Yelp Fusion API on my front-end application, using other references in stackoverflow, but still have trouble successfully doing so.

One of the most promising methods I have tried is implementing the call in the componentWillMount() method in my React component after importing jQuery, but receive a GET failure:

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'https://api.yelp.com/businesses/search',
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     data: { 
          term: 'restaurants',
          latitude: [lat],
          longitude: [long]
     },
     success: 
         function(data) { console.log('received jsonp'); }
 });
```

Do I have a syntactic error, or am I missing something altogether? I know that Yelp Fusion's API expects an Authorization token in its Header (which I have obtained), but I am under the impression that this is unnecessary if trying to obtain JSONP.

Any help or clarity of my misconceptions is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `'https:`. Is that a typo? It should be `'https://`

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. It was a typo. The request, however, still fails.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, Fusion does not support JSONP.

However, I just developed a workaround myself and put together a bunch of documentation (with code snippets) to fetch data via the front-end.

It's available on my GitHub page, if you're interested:

https://github.com/builderLabs/Yelp-Fusion-JavaScript